# Symbolication for 0x100044000

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i have the itunes connect crash report but i didn't keep the .ipa file that i submitted.

i try to find the place where the app crash and for do that i need to do the symbolication from crash.file.

this is from crash file

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
12  AppName                     0x000000010006fa60 0x100044000 + 178784
```

My question is how to find the method(code) for 0x100044000 without ipa and dSYM files ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without the dSYM you can't do anything.

Comment: Did you use Xcode to create an archive? The archive has everything you need.

Comment: i have a dSYM for another .ipa file (same project), but not the one submitted to iTunes Connect. Do you think that could work?

Comment: No, it won't. Get the correct dSYM and ipa from the archive you created in Xcode.

Comment: i don't have it no more, because i change bundle identifier and xcode keep just the archive for the last bundle id

Comment: Xcode doesn't delete any archives. So look again if you didn't delete it yourself.

Comment: i think a find that .ipa, i changed in .zip, extracte payload but i dont find inside any .app file, components of project yes but no one .app

Comment: ok, finally i found all (ipa, app, dSym), run the command in terminal but that returns me the same crash report that i can see without all this stuff and in the frame that i am interested the hexadecimal was not replace by a method name (is still 0x100044000)